# Splitting of Forces at Low Temperatures?

Tags: forces, cosmology, electroweak, low-temperature-physics

Since the electroweak force split from the strong force during the electroweak epoch then the electroweak force split into the electromagnetic and weak force during the quark epoch, is this an indication that at low temperatures we should expect to see new forces splitting off from either the weak force or the electromagnetic force?

Additionally, is this an indication that some fundamental aspect of temperature (or perhaps energy density) is embedded in either the weak or the electromagnetic force waiting to be discovered?

Is there anything currently known of additional forces which split off at lower temperatures?